# Google map in MediaWiki not showing

Tags: mediawiki

I have upgraded MediaWiki from 1.9.3 to 1.16.1 in a new server. However, the google map is not showing in the link. It's a blank in that page but in the old server with old version it is working fine. I am not a developer so I have no clue on this. Please let me know anybody have any idea on this. you can have a look on the below links

http://new.realchicago.org/wiki/index.php/Archer_Heights

The first link in which the google map is missing.

Comment: Looks fine now...

Answer (score 1):

1. Was the extension re-installed with your upgrade?
2. Can you confirm that the extension you were using is compatible with the version of MediaWiki you are using?
3. Did you change the `LocalSettings.php` file? (i.e. does the extension rely upon any configuration settings like `$wgRawHTML` ..?)